# Grep BRE meta-characters not recognized in Cygin package search

Tags: grep, cygwin, gnu

When [searching Cygwin packages](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=latex&arch=x86_64), `latex` yields many packages.  In the returned information, the word `latex` occurs as a whole word.

I'm puzzled by why the following expressions do not generate any matches:

```
<latex>
\<latex\>
\blatex\b
```

Even if I was mistaken about what constitutes a basic regular expression (BRE), at least one of these should yield the same results as unadorned `latex`.

What am I missing about BREs and/or the use of them at the Cygwin Package Search site?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `grep -P "\blatex\b"`?

Comment: I'm not invoking grep from the command line.  I supply a Grep BRE in a search field on a search page that is linked to in the original question posted above.

Comment: The server is not fully operational https://sourceware.org/pipermail/cygwin/2020-May/244684.html. Assuming that it was capable before of what you are trying.

Comment: Hmmm.  Interesting.  The package search page has been available for decades, so I also wonder if the unavailability of full capability is a recent thing.  I can't recall whether I tried meta-characters in my past BREs.  Thanks.

Comment: IIRC the search had issues when Sourceware transfered to another server and some of its former functionality wasn't restored (intentionally).

Comment: Sad. I guess with alternative unix-like environments on Windows these days, Cygwin is receiving less attention and effort overall.  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current problem is between the new WebServer and the search script.
You can bypass with proper escaping using directly the URL.
For what I see only the version `\blatex\b` works

`https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=\\blatex\\b&arch=x86_64`

```
 Found 364 matches for \blatex\b

    R-3.6.0-1 - R: R Statistical computing language
    R-3.6.2-1 - R: R Statistical computing language
    R-3.6.3-1 - R: R Statistical computing language
    TeXmacs-1.99.12-1 - TeXmacs: WYSIWYG editor for science and math
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks, matzeri!  I found that clicking the link in your answer help.  I had to pretend to edit it, then copy the URL between the square brackets.  It seems that each single backslashed `b` displayed in the URL above needs to be escaped with a 2nd backslash.  Angle brackets don't work, regardless of whether they are escaped by 1 or 2 backslashes.

Comment: Edited for better visual effect. Also StackOverflow is modifying the URL in the wrong way.